# Add one space after double quotations “, If double quotations are not followed by (Space , “x” , “X” , or “*”)

Tags: excel, vba, text, replace

I need to add one space after double quotations `“`, If double quotations are not followed by (Space , `“x”` , `“X”` , or `“*”`). 
My provided code only works correctly with the first example.

```
Function Add_Space(str As String) As String

   Static re As New RegExp
   
    re.Pattern = "("")"
    
     re.Global = True
      re.IgnoreCase = True
        Add_Space = re.Replace(str, "$1 ")
            
End Function
```

| **Current** | **Expected Result** |
| --- | --- |
| Repair of 8"sales | Repair of 8" sales |
| Repair of 8"x12"sales | Repair of 8"x12" sales |
| Repair of 8"*12" sales | Repair of 8"*12" sales |
| Repair of 8" sales | Repair of 8" sales |

Comment: That's technically a _"[left double quotation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Unicode_symbols)"_, or _U+201c_.  And, the value that should actually be used, to denote a _[unit of inches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch)_, is called a _[double prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)#Double_prime)_, or _U+2033_.  As a recommendation, you should also be replacing the _symbol_.

Comment: Strictly speaking the question should probably specify what should happen in the case of a trailing quotation mark. Some answers below will add a space and some won't (I notice that @JvdV has included Repair 8" as a test case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I always struggle with RegEx, I tend to solve such tasks with the simple VBA functions `Split` and `Join`.

Split the input by the quote character, loop over all pieces, check if the piece starts with blank, "x" or "*" and if not, just add the space to the left. Then glue everything together again.

```
Function AdjustQuotes(s As String) As String
    Const Separator = """"
    Dim tokens() As String, i As Long
    tokens = Split(s, Separator)
    For i = 1 To UBound(tokens)
        Dim startChr As String
        startChr = LCase(Left(tokens(i), 1))
        If startChr <> " " And startChr <> "x" And startChr <> "*" Then
            tokens(i) = " " & tokens(i)
        End If
    Next i
    AdjustQuotes = Join(tokens, Separator)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: [Obligatory regex quote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems), sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Comment: The same logic would translate to a sheet formula, e.g. =LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A2,""""),TEXTJOIN("""",,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(split,1)," xX*")))," "&split,split)))

Comment: @TomSharpe: Add that as an answer, it's an interesting attempt.  However, it adds an extra space at the front (because it doesn't omit the first element as I do in my code). So you need to add a trim command.

Comment: _"... I tend to solve such tasks with the simple VBA functions ..."_.  I use the same theory, here.  _Regex_ is usually good for complex matching, or capturing, situations.  Not to mention, a basic _index-of_ routine is typically available in every coding language.

Comment: I confirm that your code works perfectly, also I admit that using own VBA functions is better 1000 times than using `Regular Expression` ,
Also getting support from people here **(Excel and VBA)** is very helpful than going to the `Regex` one @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 2):

I think universally you'd want to use a negative lookahead. A pattern like:

```
"(?![xX* ]|$)
```

If you do have access to the newly added `PY()` function you could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=PY(
    xl("A2:A5").replace(r'\"(?![xX* ]|$)', '\" ', regex=True)[0].values
)
```

This would also save you from using VBA for this.

Comment: `This would also save you from using VBA for this` - is having your formulas calculated on MS servers really the better alternative to VBA?

Comment: @GSerg, in my usecases yes since they save as '.xlsx' and do not contain macro's thus can more easily be exchanged. I can see what you are on about though and I would agree that it's sub-optimal that this function has to connect with external MS-servers. It's an alternative for OP to think about.

Comment: The output of regex is totally wrong `$1R$1e$1p$1a$1i$1r $1o$1f $18$1"$1s$1a$1l$1e$1s` . I am afraid as I have no ms365

Comment: Yeah, well it isn't widely available yet for everyone. Only on beta channel for now. Either way, I see you found your answer. Awesome. @Soma

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged VBA and regex and has appropriate answers, but I was wondering if you could do this with a sheet formula thereby avoiding issues about using either Python or VBA. I could only think of a repeated substitute (ugly) or a lambda checking each character in turn (slow). But @FunThomas's answer reminded me that splitting the string up is often a better way of doing these. He is right that the answer I suggested in my comment would add an extra space at the beginning in most cases, so I need to add a Trim:

```
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A2,""""),TRIM(TEXTJOIN("""",0,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(split,1)," xX*")))," "&split,split))))
```

Or if it was necessary to retain all blanks from the original string:

```
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A2,""""),seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(split)),TEXTJOIN("""",0,IF((NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(split,1)," xX*"))))*(seq>1)," "&split,split)))
```

[image]

If you don't have Excel 365, you can try the repeated substitute formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,""" ","@ "),"""x","@x"),"""X ","@X"),"""*","@*"),"""",""" "),"@","""")
```

where the @ sign can be replaced with any character which doesn't appear in your data.

Note that the substitute formula will add an extra space in the case of a trailing quotation mark (the last test case) while the split/join formulas will not.

Comment: I am afraid to not feedback you, as I haven't ms365 to test.

Comment: OK I will add the substitute formula which will work with earlier versions of Excel

Answer (score 2):

At beginning, I tagged my question with `Regex`, and `Regex-replace`. 
But later MR @Wiktor Stribiżew ,removed these tags !! (without unknown reason), 
Because of his high reputation on regex, So I thought without doubt that my task cannot done using regex. 
But with my little experience on regex (and try and error), I could successfully answer my question using `Regex` as below .

```
Function Add_Space_after_quotes(ByVal str As String) As String

   Static re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
     re.Global = True
      re.IgnoreCase = True
       re.Pattern = "("")([^\s|x|*])"
    Add_Space_after_quotes = re.Replace(str, "$1 $2")
    
End Function
```

[image]